# Passing environment variables to custom library with forRoot()

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, ng-modules, angular-aot

I am trying to pass environment specific variables to my own library. And I'm passing it through forRoot(). For hard-coded values i am able to pass it but for environment values when i pass it to the library, it shows as undefined.

```
const rootUrl = environment.rootURL;

@NgModule({
imports: [
// configs go in here
coachModule.forRoot(
  {
    apiURL: 'test.com',
    scoreData: {
      score: 708
    },
    rootURL: rootUrl
  }),
 ...
```

rootUrl is defined when I put a break-point on @NgModule however when i put a break-point in the library rootURL is undefined.

I am using Angular 5. I have tried googling the problem but I couldn't find any solutions.

Is this a common problem and what could be another way of passing this environment variable? Any help appreciated :)

**UPDATE:** I found out why it wasnt working properly. It was building with --aot so when i debugged, I was able to see the value of rootUrl because i was checking it on the runtime but it was passing it to my library on the compile time (with undefined value)

I am trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225993/angular-call-function-in-forroot-method) possible solution right now. If anyone has any other potential solutions, I would appreciate

**SOLUTION:** My solution was to pass the variables as functions since environment variables were compiled aot. This was it would have to execute them on the runtime.

I just created the functions like following and passed the reference to the library

```
export function getRootURL() {
   return environment.rootURL;
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate this on StackBlitz?

Comment: What if you pass some string literal instead, does that work?

Comment: @AviadP. yes it does work when i pass them as hardcoded values

Comment: Im starting to think there is a reference to environment for some reason and thats not defined whitin the library... But I tried passing it with JSON.stringify() to get rid of the reference and still no progress...

Comment: Check this out - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvwvwn

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Did you ever go anywhere with this. Have a similar requirement

Comment: @Dibzmania yea i added solution to my question!