# Passing environment variables from json to libraries

Tags: json, angular, typescript, environment-variables

I have a config.json file with the environment variables for my angular 7 app that I then load into the environment const and that as been working fine.
Once I try to pass this environment variables to the my new libraries using InjectionTokens wierd behaviors start happening.
I would like not only to know how to fix it but also what is going on if possible.

I've already tried multiple ways of importing the json file including using XMLHttpRequest.
Also tried to deep copy the object before I set it to the environment and a few more things.

My config.json file:

```
{
  "baseHref": "app",
  "apiEndpoint": "http://localhost:8080/api"
}
```

My environment.prod.ts file:

```js
import config from '../config.json';

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseHref: config.baseHref,
  apiEndpoint: config.apiEndpoint,
  testing: 'Testing'
};
console.log(environment);
```

My app.module.ts file:

```js
imports: [
  TestingModule.forRoot({
    baseHref: environment.baseHref,
    apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint,
    testing: environment.testing,
    production: environment.production
  }),
]
```

My app.module.ts file:

```js
export class TestingModule {

  static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestingModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TESTING_CONFIG,
          useValue: config,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

}
```

My testing.service.ts constructor:

```js
  constructor(@Inject(TESTING_CONFIG) private config: any) {
    console.log(this.config);
  }
```

The expected was to have all the variables with data on both console logs, but instead, the environment file one has all the data but the second console log shows apiEndpoint as null and testing as 'Testing'.

I also tried to debug the appliation and right before the forRoot it already has all the data on the environment property.

Also noticed, running this with:

```
    "aot": true,
    "buildOptimizer": true
```

Has this issue while running without these two option actually fully works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found came from a derivation of: 
[Angular call function inside forRoot method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225993/angular-call-function-inside-forroot-method)

I know pass a callback that resolves the environment variables from environment:

```
export function getConfig() {
  return {
    baseHref: environment.baseHref,
    apiEndpoint: environment.apiEndpoint,
    testing: environment.testing,
    production: environment.production
  };
}

imports: [
  TestingModule.forRoot(getConfig),
]
```

And then in the library I now go through a factory that executes whatever callback is given.

```
export function initializeConfigs(configCallback: any) {
  return configCallback();
}

export class TestingModule {

  static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestingModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CONFIG_CALLBACK',
          useValue: config,
        }, {
          provide: TESTING_CONFIG,
          useFactory: initializeConfigs,
          deps: [ 'CONFIG_CALLBACK' ]
        }
      ],
    };
  }

}
```

This makes the TESTING_CONFIG injection token contain all the data correctly with no changes required to the environment files.